# In case the user forgot the password, how can I send him a reset link?

Tags: django, django-views

In case the user forgot the password, how can I send him a reset link?

Django's `PasswordChangeView`, requests the old password, not resetting password.

Comment: You should use the **`PasswordResetView`** for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`PasswordChangeView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView) indeed asks for the old password, since this is the case where a user wants to change the password manually, and then we want to avoid the overhead of a user having to inspect their email, etc. It is however better to ask for the *old* password, since it could happen that a user has logged in, and now somebody else with (physical) access to their computer want to change the credentials to "*take over*" the account.

Another related view is the [**`PasswordResetView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) this will email the user a link to a one-time URL where the user can set a new password. This is still - to some extent - secure since we typically assume the user is the only one with access to their email.